# Tool to view Hg revision graph focussed on head splitting and merges

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, version-control, mercurial

Revision graphs can become complex. TortoiseHg does a decent job of visualizing this, for example:

[image: example Hg revision graph]

However, this is a bit too much detail to conceptually grasp how the various named branches do or do not share code. What I'm looking for is a way to visualize similar graphs, but then with these requirements:

**Important**:

- Be similar to TortoiseHg's default visualization: use visual cues (e.g. coloring) to distinguish branches, and a visual cue to see the order of commits (e.g. newest commits at the top), and show revision numbers for nodes;
- For commits between two *relevant*<sup>1</sup> split/merge commits: either condense them into one node or annotate the corresponding edge (preferred), or just hide them.
- Show more prominently which named branch a set of nodes/edges belongs to.
- Be able to select a range (period or commits).
- Give instant insight into the flow of code through branches: e.g. 1000 commits (of which 40 are splits/merges between named branches) in 8 different named branches should fit on one screen.
- Gratis.

<sup>1</sup> Only splits/merges between named branches are relevant; splits/merges *within one branch* are by default not interesting to me, I care about the flow of code between *named* branches. An option to see the second type as well is a "Nice to have", see below.

**Nice to have**:

- Option to indicate splits/merges within one named branch are also important. (See <sup>1</sup>, above.)
- See author of commits.
- Tooltip with summary of a "condensed" node/edge (see requirement above).

Is there any piece of gratis software that fits my needs? Can TortoiseHg perhaps even do it? Or should I switch to another Hg GUI that has this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little playing about TortoiseHg can do more or less what you are asking for by using the `revset` filter on the filter bar.

First ensure that the filter bar is visible by selecting in the view menu or pressing ctrl-S then in the revset filter try entering:

```
children(branchpoint() or merge()) or parents(branchpoint() or merge())
```

This should select a view of all the children and parents of those changesets that are either branch or merge points.  I am sure that with a little more playing with changesets you can get more or less exactly what you need.

Sorry about the fuzzing but must respect confidentiality:
[image: Fuzzed Example]